# Ionic 2 routing without hashbangs #

Tags: angular, .htaccess, ionic2, url-routing

I am writing an app that makes use of routing. When exploring the available options I decided to avoid the hashbang approach. From what I understand in order to avoid getting 404 when accessing specific links on the page, one has to rewrite all the requests to the index file ("/" path).

I managed to find information on how to do this via .htaccess but had no luck in finding out how to achieve this in Ionic 2. I have tried adding the .htaccess file in various places of my app with no luck. I even tried writing gibberish inside of it in an attempt to generate an error, but no such thing occurred. This leads me to believe that the file is being ignored.

I managed to get routing to work with the `hash` location strategy both by using the angular router as well as the Deep Linker, but found myself unable to get it to work with the `path` location strategy.

Any advice on how to achieve this using Ionic 2 and the `ionic serve` command would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!